# How to get the string that is placed within two star symbols * like StackOverflow

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3

How can I get the string that is placed within two **star symbols** - * - like StackOverflow here?

For instance,

```
$string_1 = 'this is the *string I want to display only*';
```

or

```
$string_2 = 'this is the * string I want to display only *';
```

note that there are spaces on the second string.

I want to return this only,

```
string I want to display only
```

Using regex is what I can think of... any ideas?

Comment: This is somewhat underspecified. What do you want to have happen if the string contains more than two `*`s?

Comment: good question! I think then it should return the entire string with the stars.

Comment: It's StAckOverflow. It's at the top of every page; I'm not sure how you misspelled it twice. :)

Comment: sorry Ken... it's a late night... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   $string_1 = 'this is the *string I want to display only*';

    if(preg_match_all('/\*(.*?)\*/',$string_1,$match)) {            
            var_dump($match[1]);            
    }
```

Comment: This won't work as well as tandu's answer. The string `hello *cruel* *world*` would return just one result: `cruel* *world`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple regular expression:

This will store all matches in the variable `matches`.

```
$string = "This string *has more* than one *asterisk group*";
preg_match_all('/\*([^*]+)\*/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regular Expression solution**

```
$string_2 = 'this is the * string I want to display only *'; 
$pattern = "/(\*)+[\s]*[a-zA-Z\s]*[\s]*(\*)+/";
preg_match($pattern, $string_2, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

**PHP String functions solution, using: strpos(), strlen() and substr()**

```
$string = 'this is the * string I want to display only *'; 
$findme   = '*';
$pos = strpos($string, $findme); // get first '*' position
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    // a new partial string starts from $pos to the end of the input string
    $part = substr($string,$pos+1,strlen($string)); 
    // a new partial string starts from the beginning of $part to the first occurrence of '*' in $part
    echo substr($part,0,strpos($part, $findme)); 
}
```